# How can I get to my desktop on Linux Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.04, acpi, canonical-livepatch, 22.10

After work today I couldn't type my password to log back into my computer, I restarted it and it said something along the lines of "can't update because packages have not been updated" so in the command line I updated all the packages I could ass then tried to upgrade. I was on Linux Ubuntu 22.04, and now I'm on 22.10 Kinetic Kudu I believe. I feel like there was something wrong with the update and transition.

Now I see an error screen then it goes right to the command line, without the desktop. I searched for several errors and tried to clean things as much as I knew how, I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place now. I have work tomorrow and I need to be able to get back to my desktop. I have a USB with the old version of Ubuntu but I don't want to delete the files I have on my system now.

```
is beyond end of object (length 0xc) (20220331/exoparg2-393)
[ 0.453271].ACPI Error: Aborting method \_s8.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.USR1._PLD due to
Previous error (AE_AMl_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20220331/psparse-529)
[ 0.453381] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index. (0x00000000D)
Is beyond end of object (length 0xc) (20220331/exoparg393)
[ 0.453391] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.USR2.PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20220331/psparse-529)
[ 0.631084] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean loop6: unable to read RDB block 8
[ 3.279315] Dev loops6: unable to read RDB block 8
[ 3.846915] ==============================================
[ 3.846935] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-3Zc9YS/linux-5.1
[ 3.846953] index 7 is out of range for type 'u32 [7]'
[ 3.847013] ==============================================
[ 3.847026] ==============================================
[ 3.847039]UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-3Zc9YS/linux-5.1
[ 3.847057] index 7 is out of range of type 'u32 [7]'
[ 3.847102] ==============================================
[ 3.510853] Dev loops43: unable to read RDB blocks 8
[ 4.510853] Dev lop43: unable to read RDB block 8
[ 5.103361] ACPI BIOS Error (bug}: Could not resolve system [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_N OT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[ 5.103394] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/paparse-529)
[ 5.2225559] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: event 0x02
[FAILURE] failed to start service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical.livepatchd.

----------
Error executing enable:livepatchd error: The platform Ubuntu 22.10 is not supported
-----
Livepatch is not available for ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kuu)
```

The first error image I see
[image]

The second error image I see along with my computer specs
[image]

Here are a few commands I tried, when I saw it said I had a lot of stuff to upgrade before I update I started trying to install them 1 by 1, then I figured out installed them all, after that, I thought it was an issue with livepatch so I got tokens and authenticited 1 to live patch, uninstalled live patch, reinstalled live patch, refreshed live patch, then I tried going into recovery mode trying to clean things and cleanse the issue.

The first thing I tried was

See /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

But that doesn't seem like an actual command

Apt list --upgradable

Apt list install ubuntu-minimal( here is when I was installing them manually)

Sudo apt install --help
Sudo apt install upgrade
Sudo apt install full-upgrade (this is when I realized I could install all the needed packages

I'll update more

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us exactly what commands you ran. It's hard to know how to undo something without knowing what was done.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clean up the question a bit guys

Comment: Second error: run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Read the output carefully. Your next troubleshooting steps will be in that output.

Comment: You’ve got a usb with 22.04 on it … take the opportunity to use it in a live session to back up all your files in case you destroy your system as you try to repair it.

Answer (score 1):

The first error you are encountering is due to Canonical Livepatch.

> Error executing enable:livepatchd error: The platform Ubuntu 22.10 is not supported

- Livepatch is available for LTS releases of Ubuntu ONLY
- Your Ubuntu 22.10 is not an LTS release. (22.04 is an LTS)

Disable Livepatch by running `sudo snap stop --disable canonical-livepatch`